# How to Apply PercentFormatter for a NumberBox(winui) in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I want to add Percentage at the end(0%-100%). It shows % correctly, but it add more zeros at the end like this,

[image]

```
    double number = 75;
    NumberBox numberBox = new NumberBox {  };
    numberBox.Minimum=0;
    numberBox.Maximum=100;
    PercentFormatter percentFormatter = new PercentFormatter();
    percentFormatter.FractionDigits = 0;
    percentFormatter.IntegerDigits = 1;
    numberBox.NumberFormatter = percentFormatter;
    numberBox.Value=number;
```

Comment: yeah................!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, the value is `75`.

The value of `75` displayed as a percentage is `7500%`. The value of `0.75` displayed as a percentage is `75%`.

So you just need to make the value correctly before assign it to the **NumberBox**.

Like this:

```
 numberBox.Value = number/100;
```

Comment: Yeah, It work. But, If I set Minimum as 0 and Maximum as 100 for NumberBox. When I Increment it, it goes beyond the maximum upto 10000%.The same problem comes here. I had updated the code. Kindly check it.

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam The value of `100` displayed as a percentage is `10000%`. Please replace your last line of code with the code I posted. Use `number/100` before you assign the value.